# Making a navigation out of a matrix?

Tags: matrix, navigation

I have a matrix with only one block type. and it only has videos ID's it (videoID).

I would like to have this videoID in the url and then fetch the corresponding Matrix Row.

http://www.example.com/segment-1/segment-2/videoID

That said: I know I could get the matrix row ID like this:

```
{% set test = craft.myMatrixField.id(craft.request.lastSegment()) %}
Video Id: {{ test.videoID }}
```

But as the ID will change when reordering the matrix, I would like something more Permalink like and use the videoID in the URL.

Anybody knows how to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Craft's advanced routing](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing#advanced-routing). You'll need to define a regex pattern in order to create the named subpattern that you want, but once you've done that you can access the variable directly in your template.

In the following example {{ year }} and {{ month }} become available as variables in the news/_archive template

```
'news/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})' => 'news/_archive',
```